# Exclude specific page urls from Keycloak Authentication

Tags: angularjs, keycloak, keycloak-angular

In my angularjs application, I am using keycloak-js and integrated authentication via keycloak.
The users can join our application via invite. A unique invite url will be sent & the user will visit this page & provide their personal details to join the application.

The join page has the url as https://domainurl.com/#/register/inviteCode

I don't wish to use the default register page from keycloak, instead would like to continue using my customized register page.

Since I have integrated keycloak theme now, when the user visits the register page, it is automatically redirecting to the login page of keycloak theme.

I would like to exclude this page from keycloak authentication process. I already tried bearerExcludedUrls keycloak config & it doesn't help.

I referred to this article.
https://medium.com/@naif.alzubaidi7/how-to-exclude-some-angular-components-from-authentication-in-keycloak-795046af98df. However, "nonsecured" pages doesn't work without authentication.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you resolved this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: we created a separate domain for registration. Moved this page to it. We have done the same for forgot password too.